# Suche ein geeignetes Wort für umgangssprachlich "unfit"

Tags: single-word-request, colloquial, loanword, standard-german

Oft im Zusammenhang mit Sport oder Gesundheit, aber auch im beruflichen Umfeld und bezüglich der geistigen Leistungsfähigkeit hört man das Wort ***"unfit"***, das als Verneinung von *"[fit sein](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/fit)"* gebildet wird.

**Beispiele:**

> - Das Camp ist hart, der Trainer bescheinigte den Studenten anfangs: "Ihr seid unvorstellbar unfit." <sup>[Spiegel Online](http://www.spiegel.de/unispiegel/wunderbar/studenten-spielen-antike-per-altroemische-diaet-zum-gladiator-a-710463.html)</sup>
> - Junge Erwachsene sind erschreckend unfit. <sup>[Focus Online](http://www.focus.de/fotos/junge-erwachsene-sind-erschreckend-unfit_mid_1171311.html)</sup>
> - "Im Zweifelsfall lieber fit und etwas moppelig als schlank und unfit", sagt Ingo Froboese vom Zentrum für Gesundheit der Sporthochschule Köln. <sup>[Zeit](http://www.zeit.de/wissen/gesundheit/2012-05/gewicht-wohlbefinden-diaet/seite-2)</sup>
> - "Ich bin heute wieder mal schrecklich unfit." <sup>Mein Kollege heute früh</sup>

Nun handelt es sich hier um ein zwar gebräuchliches aber wenig definiertes Wort, das in den gängigen Wörterbüchern (noch) nicht aufgeführt ist. Mein Versuch, es in die deutsche Hochsprache zu "übersetzen", scheiterte bislang an entweder der entsetzlichen Holprigkeit der Alternativen oder an der nicht so ganz treffenden Bedeutung:

> *"eingeschränkte Leistungsfähigkeit", "reduzierte Verfassung", "müde", ...*

Gibt es eine ähnlich prägnante Alternative zu *"unfit"*?

Comment: Unfassbar, dass du dafür Quellen in renommierten Zeitungen gefunden hast. Ich habe das Wort übrigens noch nie gehört. Letztes Beispiel würde man eher mit den Worten "Ich fühle mich heute nicht gut." / "Ich bin heute nicht gut drauf." oder so ähnlich ausdrücken. Im ersten Beispiel verwände ich "untrainiert" oder "nicht in Form", aber auch hier würde ich eher den ganzen Satz umformen.

Comment: "Ihr seid in unvorstellbar schlechter körperlicher Verfassung" - Hmm, definier doch noch mal "prägnant" ;)

Comment: Wow, @Em1, das liest sich fast wie ein Kommentar von user unknown ;) (sorry fürs OT)

Comment: Ich habe auch keine gute Idee, wie man es nennen könnte. Aber `unfit` scheint es laut [Google-Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unfit%2C+untrainiert&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=)  schon länger zu geben.

Comment: @knut: die unglaubliche Häufigkeit von *"unfit"* im Google Ngram kommt vermutlich daher, dass von Google eingescannte in **Fraktur** gesetzte Werke *"unser"* fälschlich als *unfit* klassifizieren. Siehe z.B. [hier](http://books.google.de/books?id=KZYtAAAAYAAJ&dq=unfit&hl=de&pg=PA8#v=onepage&q=unfit&f=false)

Comment: @Takkat +1 für deine Recherche. Gibt aber leider keine Reputation.

Comment: @knut: hat aber Spaß gemacht ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Nicht in Form" wäre der Begriff, der es für mich am besten beschreiben würde.

Answer (score 4):

Mir fällt ein: matt, lahm. (Wahrscheinlich wieder zu umgangssprachlich: schlaff, schlapp.)

Comment: "Ihr seid ein lahmer Haufen" könnte der Trainier durchaus sagen. "Schlaff" und "Schlapp" finde ich auch gut. Nur "matt" drückt für mich aus, dass man nach langer körperlicher Anstrengung nicht mehr kann. In aller Regel ist man aber fit, nur halt ausgepowert.

Answer (score 4):

*untrainiert* könnte auch passen.

Comment: und unsportlich

Comment: Hm. Jemand der untrainiert ist, muss nicht zwangsläufig auch unsportlich sein, oder?

Answer (score 3):

**Ausser Form** oder alle anderen Variationen mit Form

**schlecht in Form**, **in schlechter Form**, **nicht in Form**...